# Cocos2D 3.0 ObjectiveChipmunk/ObjectiveChipmunk.h file not found?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, chipmunk

I am trying to integrate Cocos2D 3.0 into my project and the last error I face is: 'ObjectiveChipmunk/ObjectiveChipmunk.h' file not found - CCPhysics+ObjectiveChipmunk.h

Now CCPhysics+ObjectiveChipmunk.h is definitely in my project. I have included the following in my target's header search paths:

```
$(SRCROOT)/Chipmunk/include

$(SRCROOT)/Chipmunk/objectivec/include
```

I also included the Chipmunk folder that Cocos2D 3.0 came with, but it seems to be empty for some odd reason. If anyone knows how to figure this out, please let me know!

Comment: run the install.sh script and get the code from the xcode templates dir, the objc chipmunk files are not in the distribution, they are downloaded by the install script (for the time being)

Comment: @LearnCocos2D thanks that did the trick! Wish they were just a little more specific when installing the library into an already existing project!